# How to pass a variable from a php file to an Android activity?

Tags: java, php, android, json, mysqli

I have created an app with 2 activities. In the first activity i am inserting some records into a mysql database using a php file on a web server that looks like this:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        require 'connection.php';
        createUsername();
    }

    function createUsername() {

        global $connect;

        $username = $_POST["username"]; 

        $query = " INSERT INTO statistics(username) VALUES ('$username');";
        $result = $connect->query($query);

        $lastInsertId = $connect->insert_id; // I need this variable    
    }
?>
```

In the second activity i simply display the records using another php file that looks like this:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        include 'connection.php';
        showUserName();
    }

    function showUserName() {
        global $connect;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM statistics ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC";

        $result = $connect->query($query);
        $numberOfRows = $result->num_rows;

        $temp_array = array();

        if($numberOfRows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $temp_array[] = $row;
            }
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("statistics"=>$temp_array));
    }
?>
```

When the records are inserted in the first activity, there is a variable named `$lastInsertId`. I need to use this variable in my app activity, that looks like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("statistics");
            for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject student = users.getJSONObject(i);

                String userName = student.getString("username");

                statistics.append(userName + " \n");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What do i need to do, to pass that variable from the php file to my Android activity?

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting it correct, you can print the `$lastInsertId` as json response like you did for your second service. When you hit the first service and after it returns you the json response you can save that value using `shared preference` in app.That way it will persist. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: I didn't understand you entirely. Can you please show me how?